# How would one sync text from one form to another?

Tags: c#, winforms

English is not my native language so please bear with me.

What I meant by my question is that how would one make a form (`form 2`, for example) display what is being typed from `form 1`, like in real time. I assume the 
`TextChanged` event would be used but what's the next step?

Comment: Does form1 have a reference to form2, or does form2 have a  reference to form1, or do they both have a reference to some other object?

Comment: Technology has improved a lot, there are plenty of choices now for real time communication. May be 'SignalR' can help you on this, or you can even create your own implementation with WebSockets

Comment: @Thangadurai SignalR is a library for web pages, not normal programs. Websockets is plain overkill to spin up a web server for communicating two forms. Why not simply copying a variable between two textboxes?

Comment: @AdamG what does it mean to have a reference?

Comment: For example, does form1 have variable with your form2 instance in it or vice versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep it simple and OOP-friendly, I would make a property in `Form2` and update it in the `Form1.TextChanged` event:

### Form1.cs

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Form2 _form2;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.textBox1.TextChanged += (sender, e) => 
        { 
            _form2.TextBoxValue = textBox1.Text; 
        };

        _form2 = new Form2();
        _form2.Show();
    }
}
```

### Form2.cs

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public string TextBoxValue
    {
        get => textBox1.Text;
        set => textBox1.Text = value;
    }

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Note that you would need to change the `Form1` and `Form2` names to the actual form class names in your application (as well as the `textBox1` name).

**Edit**:
As requested in the comments, if you want changes to either textbox to be updated in both forms, you need to add the `TextBoxValue` property to both  forms, and make the event handlers in both forms change that property. I've also cleaned up the code a little.

### Form1.cs

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Form2 _form2;

    public string TextBoxValue
    {
        get => textBox1.Text;
        set => textBox1.Text = value;
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.textBox1.TextChanged += (sender, e) => 
        { 
            _form2.TextBoxValue = textBox1.Text; 
        };

        _form2 = new Form2();
        _form2.Show();
    }
}
```

### Form2.cs

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private Form1 _form1;

    public string TextBoxValue
    {
        get => textBox1.Text;
        set => textBox1.Text = value;
    }

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.textBox1.TextChanged += (sender, e) => 
        { 
            _form1.TextBoxValue = textBox1.Text; 
        };

        this.Shown += (sender, e) => 
        { 
            _form1 = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["Form1"]; 
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I can't upvote it due to the reputation thing.

Comment: What do I do if I need it to be two-way? I tried copying some of the codes from Form1 to Form2 but I'm getting a `System.NullReferenceException`.

Comment: @adaaaaamn I'll edit my answer to include two-way. Even thought you can't upvote, you can still mark it as the accepted answer if it answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

Throw an event on form2 and call it from form1

On Form1:

```
private Form2 frm2;

public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var text = Textbox1.Text;
        frm2.TextChanged.Invoke(text , new EventArgs());
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frm2 = new Form2();
       frm2.Show();
    }
```

and on form2:

```
        public EventHandler TextChanged;

 public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TextChanged += HandleTextChanged;
    }


    private void HandleTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = (string) sender;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer not to let the two forms know each other.
You can instead do something like this:

```
static class Program
{
  private static Form _form1;
  private static Form _form2;
  public static void Main()
  {
     _form1 = new MyForm();
     _form2 = new MyForm();
     _form1.MyTextbox.OnTextChanged += Form1_MyTextBox_TextChanged;
  }

  private void Form1_MyTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
       _form2.MyTextBox.Text = _form1.MyTextbox.Text;
  }
  }
}

public class MyForm : Form 
{
  public TextBox MyTextBox {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: What is `MyForm`?

Comment: A Form containing a TextBox.

Comment: Do I need to put the `Main` method to a button of `MyForm`?

Comment: The static void Main method is the one called when starting your application. It's usually in Program.cs.